# how to save data on plist file in cocoa touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SavingDataViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextField *field1;

}
@property (nonatomic , retain ) IBOutlet UITextField *field1;

-(NSString *) pathOfFile;
-(void) applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *) notification;


@end




@implementation SavingDataViewController
@synthesize field1;

-(NSString *) pathOfFile
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *doucumentFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [doucumentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"myFile.plist"];

}
-(void) applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:field1.text];
    [array writeToFile:[self pathOfFile] atomically:YES];
    [array release];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *filePath = [self pathOfFile];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        field1.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        [array release];
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];



    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

i want save a data on plist file with this code , but when i restart program , i have problem in this line : 
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);   have error : program recieved signal

what my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

does it actually save the file?! What's in the file when you open it manually.
you may want to concatenate your document path by using stringByAppendingPathComponent rather than stringByAppendingFormat as I think the documents path doesn't have a trailing path separator.